# Is it possible to update a HTML (innerHTML) with NodeJS over a TCP Server?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, server, tcpserver

I dont know how can I get my data from tcp server into a html file. I would like to send messages from a Java Application to a server. If the server received the message it should update HTML with content.
The request is succesfull but I have no idea how can I transmit the data to a Html Site and I dont know how I can start this site.

Sry for this question, I am new in NodeJS

That's my server.js:

```
var net = require('net');
const port = 3000;
const host = '127.0.0.1';

const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});

let sockets = [];

server.on('connection', function (sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    sockets.push(sock);

    sock.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    });
});
```

This is my further HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Java simple request:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class NodeJsEcho { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket s = null;
        s =  new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        ps.write("TEST");
        ps.flush();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe consider using `socket.io` to communicate and update your HTML.

In order to do so, and based on your code, this might be an example (make sure you edit it to fit your purposes):

NodeJS:

```
const net = require('net');
const port = 3000;
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const server = net.createServer();
const io = require("socket.io").listen(4000);
let socketio=undefined;
let sockets = [];

io.on('connection', socket=>{
    socketio=socket;
});

server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});


server.on('connection', sock => {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    sockets.push(sock);
    socketio.emit('updateHtml', {key: "value"});
    sock.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">changeMe</div>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js" />
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');

        socket.on('updateHtml', function (data) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data.key;
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function () { });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) It helps me.